# How to set a CloudWatch Subscription Filter to all lambda logs in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a subscription filter that will watch the logs of every one of my lambdas.

I want to do something like this:

```
AlarmSubscription:
    Type: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter
    DependsOn: AlarmFunctionPermission
    Properties: 
      DestinationArn: !GetAtt AlarmFunction.Arn
      FilterPattern: "[ALARM]"
      LogGroupName: /aws/lambda/*
```

Where the `LogGroupName` is set to all the aws lambdas. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly enough it is not possible to have a wildcard int he [`LogGroupName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-subscriptionfilter.html#cfn-cwl-subscriptionfilter-loggroupname). And since it is also not possible to have loops in cloudformation, it seems you'll have to create an entire resource for each Lambda you want to monitor.

If you want it to be dynamic, you might need to look at some other solution in which you trigger a function that creates the subscription filter each time a new log group for a lambda function is created.